# How to loop through elements that appear after an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I'm going to be able to post an answer to this in a few minutes...

Here's an example:

```
<script>
function ClearAndRunFuncs(element) {
//Clears answers to elements that are AFTER this element that HAVE an onchange
//Runs the unique onchange function to EACH element after clearing the answer
}
function FuncA(element) {
//does stuff
}
function FuncB(element) {
//does different stuff
}
function FuncC(elements) {
//does different stuff
}
function FuncD(element) {
//does different stuff
}
</script>


<select name=YesNo onchange="FuncA(this);ClearAndRunFuncs(this)">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select><br>
<br>
<input name=RandomInputA>
<select name=SomeOtherSelect onchange="FuncB(this);ClearAndRunFuncs(this)">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select><br>
<br>
<select name=AnotherSelect onchange="FuncC(this);ClearAndRunFuncs(this)">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select><br>
<br>
<input name=RandomInputB onchange="FuncD(this)">
<select name=LastSelect onchange="FuncE(this);ClearAndRunFuncs(this)">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
</select><br>
```

I want to reset the answers to element's that appear after the initial element is changed and run their corresponding functions (ClearAndRunFuncs(this);).

If you'd like a reason why, this type of code would help me to give a user a list of questions, and if they happen to answer them out of order, it would force them to re-answer questions that may branch in a different direction without needing to re-answer some fields that don't affect branching.

If you answer this with jquery, I'd appreciate extra details on whats happening since I'm new to jquery. The best answer would ideally have both javascript and jquery solutions with a detailed explanation of the jquery. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Could not understand the question...

Comment: When select element named "YesNo" is changed, it should clear element named "LastSelect" and run FuncE, clear "RandomInputB" and run FuncD, and so on...

Comment: When "RandomInputB" is changed, it only clears "LastSelect" and runs FuncE because that is the only element after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up using:

```
function ClearAndRunFuncs(element) {
var str = element.nextSibling;
var inputTypes = ["INPUT", "SELECT"];
   while(str.name != "Stop") {
      if(inputTypes.indexOf(str.tagName) > -1) {
         if(str.onchange != null) {
            str.value="";
            str.onchange();
         }
      }
   var str = str.nextSibling;
   }
}
```

at the end of my script I wrote a `<input name=Stop type=hidden>` to stop the while loop.